# Link errors for a 2D maze game in C++ - darkGDK

Tags: c++

Errors:

> 1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __malloc_dbg referenced in function "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int)"
>   (??2@YAPAXIABU_DebugHeapTag_t@std@@PADH@Z)
>
> 1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __free_dbg referenced in function "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int)" (??3@YAXPAXABU_DebugHeapTag_t@std@@PADH@Z)
>
> 1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)"
>   (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z)

What do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft Visual Studio, try adding `msvcrt.lib` to your additional dependencies in the linker settings of your project configuration.

Otherwise, you'll need to link against `msvcrt.lib`.